# Unable to get access token using Resource Owner Password Credential flow

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to implement Password Credentials flow in ASP Net Core. The idea is we created a service account (user@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com) with Global Administrator role where this will read information on users behalf.

I also created app in app registration page and resource owner user flow as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga).

By following the instructions in this [document](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/06/testing-b2c-resource-owner-password-credentials-ropc-policies-using-postman/) to test my created ROPC, I encountered the error as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The application is created in the Azure AD B2C -> App Registrations and I don't know why my ROPC is not working.

I really appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: Did you set "Supported account types" to "Accounts in any organizational directory or any identity provider. For authenticating users with Azure AD B2C. " when creating the app?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered the application as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-an-application) and the account type should be "`Accounts in any organizational directory or any identity provider. For authenticating users with Azure AD B2C.`".

For Testing Use the below Url and check the screenshot on how to pass the parameters

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]